# Node FTP download files from one server and upload to another server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp, stream

I've been looking around for a while now and [this](https://bountify.co/node-js-script-for-copying-files-between-two-ftp-locations) is the only resource I've found on the internet related to my problem. I'm trying to download files from one ftp server then upload them to another ftp server, one by one using promises and without having to save the files locally during the process.

First I'm calling client.List() recursively from `ftp` module to get an array of file paths I'll need to download from the source ftp server. This works fine.

```
getRecursively(client, path) {
    var _this = this;
    let downloadList = [];
    let paths = [];
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.list(path, function(err, list) {
            async function loop() {
                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    if (list[i].type == 'd') {
                        let _list = await _this.getRecursively(client, path + '/' + list[i].name)
                        downloadList = downloadList.concat(_list);
                    } else {
                        if ( list[i].name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg)$/i) ) {
                            downloadList.push({path: path, name: list[i].name});
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log("One complete");
                resolve(downloadList);

            }

            loop();
        })
    })
    return promise;

}
```

Next, I'm looping through the list of file paths and sending off promises which are throttled using `es6-promise-pool` module, so right now its concurrency limit is set to 10.

This is what each promise looks like:

```
getAndInsert(file) {
    let _this = this;
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let c = new Client();
        c.on('ready', () => {
            let d = new Client();
            d.on('ready', () => {
                c.get(file.path + '/' + file.name, function(err, stream) {
                    if (err) {console.log(err); console.log("FILE NAME: " + file.name)}
                    d.put(stream.pipe(passThrough()), '/images/' + file.name, function() {
                        _this.uploadCount += 1;
                        _this.uploadedImages.push(file.name)
                        console.log(_this.uploadCount + '/' + _this._list.length + " uploaded.")
                        c.end();
                        d.end();
                        resolve(true);
                    });

                });

            })

            d.on('error', (err) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                _this.onCompleteCallback();
            })

            d.connect(destinationFTP);
        })

        c.on('error', (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            _this.onCompleteCallback();
        })

        c.connect(sourceFTP);

    })
    return promise;
}
```

Each promise makes its own connection to the source and destination ftp server. I'm using the `stream` module's `Transform` object as well when I call `d.put(stream.pipe(passThrough())`. Here is that function.

```
    const passThrough = () => {
       var passthrough = new Transform();
       passthrough._transform = function(data, encoding, done) {
           this.push(data);
           done();
       };
       return passthrough;
   }
```

Finally, here is the main code that fires off the promises.

```
*buildPromises(list) {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        yield this.getAndInsert(list[i]);
    }
}

let iterator = _this.buildPromises(list);
var pool = new PromisePool(iterator, 10);
pool.start()
    .then(function(){
        console.log("Finished")
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log("error processing pool promise");
    })
```

This will go through and build the list just fine, however when I send the promises off I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: write after end
at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:236:12)
at Transform.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:287:5)
at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:639:20)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at Socket.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:475:10)
at flow (_stream_readable.js:846:34)
at Transform.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:707:7)
at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
```

It might make it through like 5 and then error out, and sometimes more, but it seems to be pretty consistent. I've also noticed sometimes I'll get similar errors saying that 'The file is already in use', but each file im uploading has a unique name. Any help is appreciated, and if you need any more info I'll do my best to provide more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution. In my `getAndInsert()` function  was doing:

```
c.get(file.path + '/' + file.name, function(err, stream) {
    if (err) {console.log(err); console.log("FILE NAME: " + file.name)}
    d.put(stream.pipe(passThrough()), '/images/' + file.name, function() {
       _this.uploadCount += 1;
       _this.uploadedImages.push(file.name)
       console.log(_this.uploadCount + '/' + _this._list.length + " uploaded.")
       c.end();
       d.end();
       resolve(true);
    });
});
```

The problem resided in `stream.pipe(passThrough())`. It seemed as if I was trying to write after the `stream` had already ended. This is what solved my problem:

```
let chunks = [];
stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
     chunks.push(chunk);
})
stream.on('end', () => {
   d.put(Buffer.concat(chunks), '/images/' + file.name, function() {
      _this.uploadCount += 1;
      _this.uploadedImages.push(file.name)
      console.log(_this.uploadCount + '/' + _this._list.length + " uploaded.")
      c.end();
      d.end();
      resolve(true);
   });
})
```

When new data is available from the stream push to an array called `chunks`. When the stream is finished, call `.put` and pass in `Buffer.concat(chunks)`

Hope this helps anyone going through a similar problem.